# How to parse follow date in Java?

Tags: java, date, format

Hello i need to parse this string

Sun, 15 Aug 2010 3:50 PM CEST

I'm using SimpleDataFormat in this way

```
String date = "Sun, 15 Aug 2010 3:50 pm CEST";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy h:mm a Z");
Date d = formatter.parse(date);
```

but it throws an exception.

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: My crystal ball isn't working.. can you please tell us what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is sensitive to the [`Locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) that is currently set. So it can be that there is a problem when trying to parse the format with your current one. With your constructor it uses `Locale.getDefault()` to determine the setting.

You could try to create the `DateFormat` explicitly using the `Locale.US` via `new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US)` and verify if the problem also exists in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
try {
    String date = "Sun, 15 Aug 2010 3:50 pm CEST";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy h:mm a Z");
    Date d = formatter.parse(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Prints (without any exception):

```
Sun, 15 Aug 2010 3:50 PM +0200
```

So I guess something else is your problem... What is the exception you get?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved in this way

```
try {
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);
Date d = df.parse(date);
bean.setDate(d);
```

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.error("Error while parsing data");
}

Remove Z from pattern and use Locale.US.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My code is

```
try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy h:mm a Z", Locale.US);
    Date d = df.parse(date);
    bean.setDate(d);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.error("Error while parsing data");
}
```

and exception is

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Mon, 16 Aug 2010 2:20 pm CEST
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Works fine for me on JDK 1.5.0_14. And your input equals "Mon, 16 Aug 2010 2:20 pm CEST" without any additional whitespaces/characters?