# How do I convert the date from one format to another date object in another format without using any deprecated classes?

Tags: java

I'd like to convert a date in date1 format to a date object in date2 format.

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2012, 8, 21);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
    Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(date1);
    println date1
    println date2
```

Comment: I have created a simple method to do this. refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042733/4531507

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29):

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = originalFormat.parse("August 21, 2012");
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);  // 20120821
```

Also note that `parse` takes a `String`, not a `Date` object, which is already *parsed*.

Comment: you'd need to wrap Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(formattedDate); with try catch as it'd throw parseexception.

Comment: What are the exact inputs you are trying to parse? Try this demo http://ideone.com/Hr6B0. Perhaps you are passing an invalid `Date`?

Comment: My input is a string of this format August 21, 2012 and I need to save it as another string of format 20120821

Comment: @Phoenix: Are you setting the `Locale` to `Locale.ENGLISH` of the first `SimpleDateFormat`? Otherwise, if you are on a non-english `Locale`, `August` will not be parsed correctly and will throw a ParseException.

Comment: This is what I did. I want the end output to be "20120821"   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.format("August 21, 2012");
        String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat1.format(date1);
        Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(formattedDate);

Comment: @Phoenix: `format` is to *format* the output; to parse a `Date` from a `String` you need to use `parse`. So, instead of `Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.format("August 21, 2012")`, you should have `Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("August 21, 2012")` as in my sample code.

Comment: While this answer was the best answer at the time, I should advise visitors coming to the site now that the classes used are considered legacy these days.  The answers which refer to Java 8 are now the preferred way to do this.

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "January 08, 2017" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM dd, uuuu" , Locale.US ) 
).format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE )
```

## Using java.time

The Question and other Answers use troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

You have date-only values, so use a date-only class. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
String input = "January 08, 2017";
Locale l = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM dd, uuuu" , l );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

Your desired output format is defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. For a date-only value, the “expanded” format is YYYY-MM-DD such as `2017-01-08` and the “basic” format that minimizes the use of delimiters is YYYYMMDD such as `20170108`.

I strongly suggest using the expanded format for readability. But if you insist on the basic format, that formatter is predefined as a constant on the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class named [`BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/OHHak9).

> ld.toString(): 2017-01-08

> output: 20170108

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: It should be noted that Android apps targeting API level 26 or above (Android 8.0, O) [can use `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) directly without using ThreeTenABP. Disclaimer: I might have been involved in that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer So noted in a fresh edit to this Answer; thanks for the comment. And I'm sure all the Android developers are grateful for your work on *java.time* functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 8, we can achieve this as follows:

```
private static String convertDate(String strDate) 
{
    //for strdate = 2017 July 25

    DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy MMMM dd")
                                        .toFormatter();

    LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(strDate, f);
    DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/yyyy");

    String newDate = parsedDate.format(f2);

    return newDate;
}
```

The output will be : "07/25/2017"

Answer (score 5):

## Try this

This is the simplest way of changing one date format to another

```
public String changeDateFormatFromAnother(String date){
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    String resultDate = "";
    try {
        resultDate=outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultDate;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin equivalent of answer answered by `João Silva`

```
 fun getFormattedDate(originalFormat: SimpleDateFormat, targetFormat: SimpleDateFormat, inputDate: String): String {
    return targetFormat.format(originalFormat.parse(inputDate))
}
```

Usage (In Android):

```
getFormattedDate(
            SimpleDateFormat(FormatUtils.d_MM_yyyy, Locale.getDefault()),
            SimpleDateFormat(FormatUtils.d_MMM_yyyy, Locale.getDefault()),
            dateOfTreatment
    )
```

Note: Constant values:

```
// 25 Nov 2017
val d_MMM_yyyy = "d MMM yyyy"

// 25/10/2017
val d_MM_yyyy = "d/MM/yyyy"
```

Comment: While `SimpleDateFormat` is not officially deprecated yet, it is certainly both long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: I didn't knew about that. I will check it soon

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following method. It takes your date String as argument1, you need to specify the existing format of the date
as argument2, and the result (expected) format as argument 3.

Refer to this link to understand various formats:
[Available Date Formats](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)

```
public static String formatDateFromOnetoAnother(String date,String givenformat,String resultformat) {

    String result = "";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1;

    try {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(givenformat);
        sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(resultformat);
        result = sdf1.format(sdf.parse(date));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    finally {
        sdf=null;
        sdf1=null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  private String formatDate(String date, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) {

    String newDate;
    DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
    inputDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);
    try {
        newDate = outputDateFormat.format((inputDateFormat.parse(date)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        newDate = "";
    }
    return newDate;

}
```

Comment: While not officially deprecated, the classes `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone` are poorly designed and long outdated. Please don’t suggest using them in 2019, it’s a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help someone.

```
 public static String getDate(
        String date, String currentFormat, String expectedFormat)
throws ParseException {
    // Validating if the supplied parameters is null 
    if (date == null || currentFormat == null || expectedFormat == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    // Create SimpleDateFormat object with source string date format
    SimpleDateFormat sourceDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);
    // Parse the string into Date object
    Date dateObj = sourceDateFormat.parse(date);
    // Create SimpleDateFormat object with desired date format
    SimpleDateFormat desiredDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedFormat);
    // Parse the date into another format
    return desiredDateFormat.format(dateObj).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

             String fromDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
             String fromdate = 15/03/2018; //Take any date

             String CheckFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";//take another format like dd/MMM/yyyy
             String dateStringFrom;

             Date DF = new Date();


              try
              {
                 //DateFormatdf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
                 DateFormat FromDF = new SimpleDateFormat(fromDateFormat);
                 FromDF.setLenient(false);  // this is important!
                 Date FromDate = FromDF.parse(fromdate);
                 dateStringFrom = new 
                 SimpleDateFormat(CheckFormat).format(FromDate);
                 DateFormat FromDF1 = new SimpleDateFormat(CheckFormat);
                 DF=FromDF1.parse(dateStringFrom);
                 System.out.println(dateStringFrom);
              }
              catch(Exception ex)
              {

                  System.out.println("Date error");

              }

output:- 15/03/2018
         15 Mar 2018
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    //Convert input format 19-FEB-16 01.00.00.000000000 PM to 2016-02-19 01.00.000 PM
    SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aaa");
    Date today = new Date();        

    Date d1 = inFormat.parse("19-FEB-16 01.00.00.000000000 PM");

    SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSS aaa");

    System.out.println("Out date ="+outFormat.format(d1));
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is limited to parsing millisecond precision, and will corrupt the minutes/seconds if asked to go beyond that.