# Convert java.util.date format into another different java.util.date format

Tags: java, date-format, date-conversion, java.util.date

How Can I convert this java.util.Date format:

```
2015-01-16 00:00:00.0
```

to this java.util.Date format:

```
2015-01-16 00:00:00 GMT+00:00
```

Comment: Is it a simple case of output formatting you're considering? (And I guess the change of day from 16 to 01 is accidental)

Comment: This is the same date! A `Date` object has no notion of a format

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert the date from one format to another date object in another format without using any deprecated classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503527/how-do-i-convert-the-date-from-one-format-to-another-date-object-in-another-form)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Something as follows:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

would print something like this: `2001-07-04 12:08:56 PDT`.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SimpleDateFormat?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html