# Convert date with format "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS+/-0000" to "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ"

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I need to convert date string into a another specific format.

For example: I've a date which can come as `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss±0000` and I need to convert that to something `"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ"`.

I tried few things using Java 8 API but could not find a way out.

Comment: Please give some example inputs and outputs.

Comment: can you put your code which have issues?

Comment: Here is general solution: [How do I convert the date from one format to another date object in another format without using any deprecated classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12503542). Now try to specify what problem exactly is stopping you from using it. Do you get compilation errors, runtime exceptions, incorrect results, or some other problems?

Answer (score 5):

Try this (Java 8):

```
String input = "2016-10-14T14:19:40-04:00";
String output = ZonedDateTime.parse(input).toInstant().toString();
System.out.println(output); // prints 2016-10-14T18:19:40Z
```

This works because the primary format of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) used by [`parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) is [`ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME), so it will parse input in the format you described.

The output format you requested happens to be the default format of [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), as returned by its [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) method, i.e. the [`ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) format.

Converting between the two (`ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` using the [`toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--) method) will perform the timezone adjustment necessary.

Comment: Good answer, but more appropriate to use `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime` for input that only has offset and no time zone info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // or "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss±0000"
String dateInString = "1993-11-27";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateInString);

SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: This Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. See the [Answer by Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40049730/642706) for the modern solution.