# Parse String to date with datetime zone

Tags: java, datetime-format

I have a date in string format like this:

```
    String date = "2018-02-21T15:00:00.000+05:30"
```

I am trying to parse it using `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
    Date start= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ")
                                    .parse(date);
```

**But I am getting unparseable date error.Can anyone tell how to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

```
  String date = "2018-02-21T15:00:00.000+05:30";
  SimpleDateFormat start= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
  SimpleDateFormat start1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

            try
            {
              Date date1=start.parse(date);
              Date date2=start1.parse(date);
              System.out.println("Date is= " + date1); // Date is = Wed Feb 21 10:00:00 UTC 2018
             System.out.println("Date is= " + date2); // Date is = Wed Feb 21 15:00:00 UTC 2018
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception = " +e);
              }
```

Comment: check it carefully. it is working... I have tested it.  Did you change `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")`

Comment: are you sure? It is working on my side. Check my updated answer

Comment: Yeah now its working.Now after parsing can i change it to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503527/how-do-i-convert-the-date-from-one-format-to-another-date-object-in-another-form  for that refer to this..