# How to convert Date String pattern into DateTime Format format

Tags: java, jodatime

I have this Pattern of Date.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");
DateTime jodatime = new DateTime(date);
```

I need in this format.

```
public static DateTime stringToDateTime(String date) {
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(" yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
return formatter.parseDateTime(date);
     }
```

Comment: any example of input `date`?

Comment: any error? but while parsing `String` to data format that string should match to the format

Comment: I already answered this before to a question asked by another person.

Comment: @BingLi224
input :- 2019-01-15

Comment: @Purushottam input to `stringToDateTime(String date)`?

Comment: @SamzSakerz that Date is not of Joda Api

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503527/how-do-i-convert-the-date-from-one-format-to-another-date-object-in-another-form

Comment: @BingLi224 
yes i want to that

Comment: @AnujaBarve that's for string pattern conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DateTime stringToDateTime(String date) {
    return new DateTime(new Date(date));
}
```

Here Date Default java.util.Date