# Trying to get date format in Java - calling from separate function

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve the date format depending on the month, day and year the user enters. It should be called from one function and the logic in another. When I run the code, the questions run but the date is not outputted even though it is being returned to the getArrivalDate method. Any ideas?

CODE:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Reserve {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Enter the requested input");
    System.out.println();

    //Call Arrival Date Method
    getArrivalDate();
}

 public static void getArrivalDate() {
    // create a Scanner object
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";

        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

            System.out.print("month (1-12): ");
            int month = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("day (1-31):  ");
            int day = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("year: ");
            int year = sc.nextInt();  

         setArrivalDate(choice);
          //Users choice
            choice = sc.nextLine();
        }
 } //End getArrivalDate

 public static String setArrivalDate(String arrivalDate1) {

        String month = "no month";
        int day = 0;
        int year = 0;

        switch(month) {
        case "1":
            month = "January";
        break;

        case "2":
            month = "February";
        break;

        case "3":
            month = "March";
        break;

        case "4":
            month = "April";
        break;

        case "5":
            month = "May";
        break;

        case "6":
            month = "June";
        break;

        case "7":
            month = "July";
        break;

        case "8":
            month = "August";
        break;

        case "9":
            month = "September";
        break;

        case "10":
            month = "October";
        break;

        case "11":
            month = "November";
        break;

        case "12":
            month = "December";
        break;
        }

 return arrivalDate1 = "Arrival Date: " + month + day + year;
      return arrivalDate1;  
}


}
```

Comment: `setArrivalDate` returns a value... You never capture it

Comment: How do I "capture" it? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Please try again. --- Why are you passing `"y"` (value of `choice`) into the `setArrivalDate` method? --- Why is `setArrivalDate` method not using the `arrivalDate1` parameter for anything? --- Why do you expect `switch("no month")` (value of `month`) to match any of those `case` statements?

Answer (score 2):

You need to at least print out the return value

And you're passing in `choice`, which is always just "y"... If you want to show the actual date, start by passing in each value

```
System.out.println(setArrivalDate(year, month, day));
```

This isn't really correct either `return arrivalDate1 = "Arrival Date: "...`. You don't have to return a variable, just return the string like `return "Arrival Date:"...`

And rather than a switch case, I suggest learning about the `DateFormatter` class

Comment: If I used the date formatter how would I apply it to my use case? Would I set it to it's own method? public String getCheckInDateFormatted(){ DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT); return dtf.format(checkInDate); }}

Comment: You're trying to convert month numbers to valid strings. Therefore, you can construct one format, then you must parse to a date object, which would be formatted to another. Examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42240771/2308683

Answer (score 0):

You are taking day, month and year as an input but not passing it to `setArrivalDate()` method. Even this method is returning some default value you are not printing anything. Here is a workable code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Reserve {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Enter the requested input");
    System.out.println();

    // Call Arrival Date Method
    getArrivalDate();
}

public static void getArrivalDate() {
    // Create a Scanner object
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

        System.out.print("month (1-12): ");
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("day (1-31):  ");
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("year: ");
        int year = sc.nextInt();

        // To remove a trailing '\n'.
        sc.nextLine();

        // You have to pass the values you got from user.
        System.out.println(setArrivalDate(day, month, year));

        // You should again dispaly a message to ask for input again.
        System.out.print("Enter 'Y/y' to continue:");

        //Users choice
        choice = sc.nextLine();
    }
} //End getArrivalDate

public static String setArrivalDate(int day, int month, int year) {
    String monthStr = "";
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            monthStr = "January";
            break;

        case 2:
            monthStr = "February";
            break;

        case 3:
            monthStr = "March";
            break;

        case 4:
            monthStr = "April";
            break;

        case 5:
            monthStr = "May";
            break;

        case 6:
            monthStr = "June";
            break;

        case 7:
            monthStr = "July";
            break;

        case 8:
            monthStr = "August";
            break;

        case 9:
            monthStr = "September";
            break;

        case 10:
            monthStr = "October";
            break;

        case 11:
            monthStr = "November";
            break;

        case 12:
            monthStr = "December";
            break;
    }

    return "Arrival Date: " + monthStr + day + year;
}
```

}

There are lot of things you can handle. First if you setup a proper format you can use `SimpleDateFormat` and clean a code little bit. Next thing is that you should be careful when you use `sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()`. `sc.nextInt()` will take the integer value and leave a newline character behind which is then taken by `sc.nextLine()`. Because of this the actual string you wanted to capture is not read.

Comment: thank you for this! I also need to do a departure date...would I follow the same convention??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter the requested input");

    //Call Arrival Date Method
    getArrivalDate();

}


private static void getArrivalDate() {
    // create a Scanner object
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String again;
    do {
        System.out.print("month (1-12): ");
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        while(month>12){
            System.out.print("Month must be between 1-12.\nTry again:");
            month=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("day (1-31):  ");
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("year: ");
        int year = sc.nextInt();

        setArrivalDate(month, day, year);
        System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue? (Y/N): ");
        again = sc.next();
    } while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

} //End getArrivalDate


private static void setArrivalDate(int month, int day, int year) {


    System.out.print("\nArrival Date: ");
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("January " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Feb " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("March " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("April " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("May " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 6:
            System.out.println("June " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 7:
            System.out.println("July " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 8:
            System.out.println("August " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 9:
            System.out.println("September " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 10:
            System.out.println("October " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 11:
            System.out.println("November " + day + " " + year);
            break;

        case 12:
            System.out.println("December " + day + " " + year);

    }
  }
}
```