# how do i change the date display format using Java that's coming from a db query?

Tags: java, sql, date

How do I change the date that displays as YYYYMMDD to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS+-ZZZZ?

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask].  Post a [mcve]

Comment: [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: how do i use the format thats coming from the query?

Comment: You might wanna look up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503527/how-do-i-convert-the-date-from-one-format-to-another-date-object-in-another-form). Hope this is, what you're looking for :)

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A real `date` or `timestamp` column does not have any format. So there is no such thing as "the format coming from a db query" as long as you properly retrieve the value using `getObject(..., LocalDate.class)` or `getObject(..., LocalDateTime.class)` or at least `getTimestamp()` or `getDate()`